# What is the best way to filter search queries - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

Im building a site where users can search the posts. Each post is stored inside a database. When a user makes a search e.g. iPad Mini FOR SALE the query will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE title REGEXP 'iPad|Mini|FOR|SALE'
```

The query will then result to these 3 items:

- Selling iPad Mini
- Selling iPad
- Looking for authentic Gold Watches

The search was successful with the first two items but the third item really just doesn't belong in the group. I want to filter it out and just show relevant items to the search. I'm thinking of taking out the common words like for, is, are, etc. but maybe you guys have any suggestions?

Side note: Do you guys recommend "REGEXP"? I just saw it, used it, and didn't dive into it yet. (No need to answer this just the search filter question, but if you have some good info that would be great.)

Comment: indexes is best way for search queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also take a look at `FULLTEXT` search.
In order to make `FULLTEXT` search work you need `MyIsam` MySQL table engine type there are innoDB support too but i don't know much about it.

Comment: I used FULLTEXT to create the table, but didn't know about FULLTEXT search. Can you give samples? I'm googling it right now but maybe you have good samples on how to do it.

Comment: @joespina do not need to google for it just see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html and see how it works..

Answer (score 1):

Already readed this topic? http://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html
Or this is also a good tutorial / explanation: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, remove common words**

These are called [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words). These are words that are generally irrelevant.

**Consider relevance**

A post titled 'ipad mini for sale' is very relevant for a user searching [ipad mini for sale]. A post titled 'ipad for sale' is less relevant. A post titled 'cheese factory for sale' is less relevant still.

Consider deriving an algorithm for calculating what you deem relevant with respect to the posts on your site and the terms searched for by users.

The algorithm may be as simple as looking at the terms searched for and the occurrence of the terms in the post title. Are all terms searched for present in the title? Probably very relevant. Are 10% of the terms searched for present in the title? Probably very irrelevant.

Consider how you want to calculate a relevance score. Set a threshold below which results are deemed too irrelevant to be present in the results. From experience, I'd suggest setting the threshold quite high and aim for highly relevant results only, perhaps listing less relevant results only if no highly relevant results can be found

**Use stemming**

As an aside, use stemming in your search. A stemming algorithm will reduce a word down to a common stem. You will search for the stem only not the full search term. Read up on [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming). Find an implementation of the porter stemming algorithm for the language you are using; it's a long-standing algorithm and from experience it's fast and pretty much good enough for most applications.

**REGEXP?**

If you remove stop words and use a stem-based approach, this will be a less relevant concern. In any case, it's a matter of implementation and is likely too subjective a matter to get you a meaningful answer. Try it, examine performance. Try another approach, examine performance. Use what works best for you.

Comment: "The algorithm may be as simple as looking at the terms searched for and the occurrence of the terms in the post title." - This opened my mind to something I would really want to learn and would be the best thing to use to accomplish a very relevant and clean search. But how do I do it? Its outside the scope of what I have learned. I think I can do it with PHP but is there a built-in function in MySQL to identify how many of the searched terms is present in the row? What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: @joespina: There would no MySQL function to achieve this; it's an application-level feature outside the scope of MySQL. You'd have to retrieve all results from MySQL and then in PHP process the results, compare each result to the terms searched for and include or exclude the results as required.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. At least I now have some direction on how to achieve search result relevance!